# How to include price in bibliography?

Tags: biblatex

I have added a `price` attribute to my bibliography as such:

```
@book{1578203120,
  Author = {Janice Reynolds},
  Title = {The Complete E-Commerce Book: Design, Build \& Maintain a Successful Web-based Business},
  Publisher = {CRC Press},
  Year = {2004},
  ISBN = {1578203120},
  URL = {http://www.amazon.com/dp/1578203120},
  price = {USD 30.55}
}
```

When I re-run my `latexmk` (which runs `bibtex` and `xelatex` the required number of times), I don't see the price show up in my bibliography. I don't get any errors or warnings either.

I'm using the following `biblatex` options:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,url=true]{biblatex}
```

**UPDATE: I ultimately got this looking how I wanted as follows:**

```
\begin{filecontents*}{biblatex-dm.cfg}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{price}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{price}
\end{filecontents*}

\NewBibliographyString{price}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{price = {price}}

\renewbibmacro*{addendum+pubstate}{%
  \iffieldundef{price}
    {}
    % {\textsc{\bibstring{price}}\addcolon\space\printfield{price}}
    {\addperiod\space\textsc{price}\addcolon\space\printfield{price}}
  \printfield{addendum}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{pubstate}}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I think you have to use/define proper bibliography style.

Comment: @Pouya okay...how?

Comment: Have you tried using the `note` for this purpose (rather than creating an entirely new field and then having to instruct biblatex what to do with this field)? By the way, you need to prefix a backslash to the `$` symbol.

Comment: `note` has no effect.

Comment: One advantage of the BibTeX format is you can use any number or arbitrary fields, and BibTeX (and Biber) will happily ignore them if they don't know what they are for.  (I often have a field for the call number of library books that I often (re-)check out.)  To make them be used in the output, you need a style (a `.bst` with BibTeX, a `.bbx` with `biblatex`/`biber`) that does something with these fields.  if you don't want to do that, for `biblatex`, usually the `addendum` field is the last thing printed, and you could put the price information there.

Comment: @jon `addendum` had no effect either. Do I need to change my `backend` option? I'm using XeLaTeX.

Comment: 'No effect' is pretty vague.  Do you mean everything works fine and shows up in the bibliography *except* the `addendum` field?  It definitely works for me, even with `backend=bibtex`.

Comment: Also: is `latexmk` definitely aware that you've changed your `.bib` file and therefore knows it needs to run the full sequence of `xelatex, biber, xelatex` again?  Try a manual run of each command just to be certain.

Comment: I ran xelatex, bibtex, xelatex, xelatex. It DOES work when I use Addendum, but not Price. I got the output I wanted by doing this: `Addendum = {Price: USD 30.55}`.

Comment: Right: `price` is not a standard field, and, as I said, both BibTeX and Biber will ignore all fields they have not been informed of. `biblatex` (with either backend) does make use of the `addendum` field if it is used.

Comment: Regarding the update, your solution will mislead others. (1) You are not actually using the bibliography strings if you are hard-coding the word 'price' into your renewed bibmacro -- maybe because you are not using `babel`..? (2) Without something like `\newunit\newblock` between your hard-coded 'price' line and the printing of the `addendum` field, my guess is that there will be problems if an entry contains both a `price` and `addendum` field. Of course, if all is working the way you like, that's all to the good; but others might not notice the small ways your solution differs from @moewe's.

Comment: Additionally to jon's comments you should note that defining the bibliography string `price` (as I did below) is unnecessary in your definition as it is never used. Here I would certainly advocate the use of bibstrings as explained below.

Comment: Also, I would be wary of printing text verbatim as in `\textsc{price}`, just add it to `\DeclareFieldFormat` like so: `\DeclareFieldFormat{price}{\textsc{price}\addcolon\space#1}`. Then you do not have to check for an empty `price` field and the macro becomes `\renewbibmacro*{addendum+pubstate}{\newunit\newblock\printfield{price}\printfield{addendum}\newunit\newblock
\printfield{pubstate}}` (modulo line breaks and `%` percent signs to prevent spurious whitepsace).

Comment: I just assumed `price` were recognized because of what I found here: https://www.cs.arizona.edu/~collberg/Teaching/07.231/BibTeX/bibtex.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could just add the information to the addendum field.

See this MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,url=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{1578203120,
  Author = {Janice Reynolds},
  Title = {The Complete E-Commerce Book: Design, Build \& Maintain a Successful Web-based Business},
  Publisher = {CRC Press},
  Year = {2004},
  ISBN = {1578203120},
  URL = {http://www.amazon.com/dp/1578203120},
  addendum = {USD 30.55},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

---

You could also map the price field to the addendum via `biber`'s sourcemapping features.
This will note overwrite the addendum, but append the price information to it (preceded by a space). Since all standard styles seem to employ `addendum` this method is quite likely to make the price appear in the bibliography.

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite=true]{
      \step[fieldsource=price, final]
      \step[fieldset=addendum, fieldvalue={~}, append]
      \step[fieldset=addendum, origfieldval, append]
    }
  }
}
```

You might like to replace the second `\step` by `\step[fieldset=addendum, fieldvalue={~\textsc{Price}:~}, append]`.

See this MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,url=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{1578203120,
  Author = {Janice Reynolds},
  Title = {The Complete E-Commerce Book: Design, Build \& Maintain a Successful Web-based Business},
  Publisher = {CRC Press},
  Year = {2004},
  ISBN = {1578203120},
  URL = {http://www.amazon.com/dp/1578203120},
  price = {USD 30.55},
  addendum = {A nice book, for less than fifty dollar.},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite=true]{
      \step[fieldsource=price, final]
      \step[fieldset=addendum, fieldvalue={~\textsc{Price}:~}, append]
      \step[fieldset=addendum, origfieldval, append]
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{1578203120,wilde}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

But with `biber` there is a much cooler way.

We define a new field `price` via a datamodel file (we use `biblatex-dm.cfg`; the file should be put somewhere LaTeX can find it; in the MWE the file is automatically created via the `filecontents` environment).

```
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=literal]{price}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{price}
```

To make use of the fancy localisation features, we also define

```
\NewBibliographyString{price}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  price = {price},
}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{%
  price = {Preis},
}
\DeclareFieldFormat{price}{\bibstring{price}\addcolon\space#1}
```

Or, if you prefer "Price" to be in small caps, try

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{price}{\bibstring[\textsc]{price}\addcolon\space#1}
```

Then, we also have `biblatex` print the `price` information.
The most stable idea would probably be to add it to the driver manually, but that is very tiresome, so we can use either of the following ways.

Add the information to the `finentry` hook.

```
\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{%
  \printfield{price}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \finentry}
```

Or, print the information just before the `addendum` field.

```
\renewbibmacro*{addendum+pubstate}{%
  \printfield{price}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{addendum}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{pubstate}}
```

The MWE uses the latter method

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,url=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{1578203120,
  Author = {Janice Reynolds},
  Title = {The Complete E-Commerce Book: Design, Build \& Maintain a Successful Web-based Business},
  Publisher = {CRC Press},
  Year = {2004},
  ISBN = {1578203120},
  URL = {http://www.amazon.com/dp/1578203120},
  price = {USD 30.55},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{biblatex-dm.cfg}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{price}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{price}
\end{filecontents*}

\NewBibliographyString{price}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  price = {price},
}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{%
  price = {Preis},
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{price}{\bibstring[\textsc]{price}\addcolon\space#1}

\renewbibmacro*{addendum+pubstate}{%
  \printfield{price}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{addendum}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{pubstate}}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's an incredible amount of work. I finally got what I wanted using `Addendum = {Price: USD 30.55}`. I just had to run xelatex, bibtex, xelatex, xelatex.

Comment: @MarkRichman -- The advantage of this solution is that if you re-use the bibliography file in another document that uses `biblatex`, and *don't* want to print the price information, you won't need to subsequently delete all these `addendum` fields that mentions the price.  The solution therefore increases the portability and therefore long-term viability of employing a single `.bib` file.  (So: if the issue of a single `.bib` file is irrelevant, it is overkill -- albeit one with a 'cool' factor, as moewe says.)

Comment: @jon I see your point! One last question - how to get "Price" in small caps to match ISBN and URL? Assuming that is *stylistically accurate* of course.

Comment: @jon Just the word "Price" in small caps. "USD 30.55" should be in the default font.

Comment: @MarkRichman -- Hmm, actually, changing the bibstrings might be best for internationalization.  (Never thought about this whole problem before.)  I think perhaps: `\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{price = {\mkbibacro{PRICE}},}` (and the same for the other languages needed) is the best way.

Comment: using `biber` as backend, you could also just remap the `price` field to `addendum` with `\DeclareSourcemap` (with something like `\DeclareSourcemap{\maps[datatype=bibtex]{\map{\step[fieldsource=price,fieldset=addendum,origfieldval]}}}`)

Comment: @henrique -- I thought about that, too.  But won't that require not using the `addendum` field for anything else (in documents where the price needs to be included as well)?  Otherwise, wouldn't you need to hardcode the string 'price' into the `addendum` field itself?

Comment: Hey @jon, that's absolutely true, I just thought it worth mentioning a poor man's alternative :)

Comment: @henrique -- Indeed.  It might be worth posting as an alternative example.

Comment: I ultimately got this looking how I wanted. See update in question.

Comment: Related [Data model macro cannot be used in preamble](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/238554/35864).