# Declare different strings for different references

Tags: biblatex

How can I declare different strings for different entry? For example, for ordinary url, the urldate will be printed as "Accessed: urldate" while for Wikipedia, the urldate will be printed as "Last modified: urldate".

I tried something like \iffieldequalstr but it seems to be not working. Below is a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=ieee,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ELECTRONIC{MEMSnet,
  title = {What is {MEMS}?},
  organization = {MEMSnet},
  url = {http://www.memsnet.org/mems/what_is.html},
  urldate = {2013-12-01},
}

@ELECTRONIC{WikiMEMS,
  author = {Wikipedia},
  title = {Microelectromechanical systems},
  organization = {Wikipedia.org},
  url = {http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microelectromechanical_systems},
  timestamp = {09:59},
  urldate = {28 November 2013}
}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\xpatchbibdriver{online}
  {\printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{date}}}
  {\iffieldundef{year}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{date}}}}
  {}
  {\typeout{There was an error patching biblatex-ieee (ieee.bbx's @online driver)}}

 \AtEveryBibitem{
  \ifentrytype{online}{
   \iffieldequalstr{author}{Wikipedia}{
     \DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
       urlseen = {Last modified}
      }
     \DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibbrackets{\bibstring{urlseen}\addcolon\space#1\addcomma\space\printfield{timestamp}}}
    }{
     \DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
      urlseen = {Accessed}
     }
     \DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibbrackets{\bibstring{urlseen}\addcolon\space#1}}
    }
   }{}
  }

\begin{document}
  \nocite{MEMSnet,WikiMEMS,wilde,markey}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: One can only modify the `bibstrings` in the preamble, so when it gets to `AtEveryBibitem` that is too late. Moreover it is not consistent to use `urldate` for what it's intended in almost all cases, but abuse it as something entirely different for Wikipedia entries. You should think about creating a custom type `@wiki` (or similar) in which `date` is prefixed by "last modified". It just does not seem to be right to use `urldate` for that; `urldates` indicates when you last saw that page, *not* when it was last modified, that almost certainly is `date`'s job.

Comment: thanks @moewe for replying all my questions on Christmas Day. Merry Christmas to you. Just wonder how can I add a custom entry type? I am actually quite new to latex

Comment: Merry Christmas to you too. There seems to be a solution to do what you want after all, but I have also written up something about custom entry types.

Comment: If this is not something you need a lot, you could also just use the addendum or note field to add this information. I tend to agree that date, rather than urldate, is the natural place for this information if you want to use a standard date field. "Last modified" seems roughly like the specification of an edition of a book, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution that comes pretty close to what you want is to do the following,
declare a new `bibstring`, aptly named `lastmodified`, via

```
\NewBibliographyString{lastmodified}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  lastmodified = {last modified}
}
```

To be able to compare the name `author` we need a macro `\wikitestname`. Unfortunately, there is as of now no easy way to check a name* against a string, so we need to use `\ifnameequals` to check against a macro; the name format is very specific however, you can look it up in the `.bbl` file.

```
\def\wikitestname{{}{{{}{Wikipedia}{W.}{}{}{}{}{}{}}}}
```

We then check whether the entry currently processed is a Wiki one

```
\AtEveryBibitem{
  \ifentrytype{online}{
    \ifnameequals{author}{\wikitestname}
      {\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibparens{\bibstring{lastmodified}\space#1}}}
      {\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibparens{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}}}
  }
}
```

and change the string preceding `urldate` accordingly if necessary.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=ieee,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ELECTRONIC{MEMSnet,
  title = {What is {MEMS}?},
  organization = {MEMSnet},
  url = {http://www.memsnet.org/mems/what_is.html},
  urldate = {2013-12-01},
}

@ELECTRONIC{WikiMEMS,
  author = {Wikipedia},
  title = {Microelectromechanical systems},
  organization = {Wikipedia.org},
  url = {http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microelectromechanical_systems},
  timestamp = {09:59},
  date = {2013-11-28},
  urldate = {2013-12-25},
}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\xpatchbibdriver{online}
  {\printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{date}}}
  {\iffieldundef{year}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{date}}}}
  {}
  {\typeout{There was an error patching biblatex-ieee (ieee.bbx's @online driver)}}


\NewBibliographyString{lastmodified}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  lastmodified = {last modified}
}

\def\wikitestname{{}{{{}{Wikipedia}{W.}{}{}{}{}{}{}}}}
 \AtEveryBibitem{
    \ifentrytype{online}{
     \ifnameequals{author}{\wikitestname}
       {\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibparens{\bibstring{lastmodified}\space#1}}} 
       {\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibparens{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}}} 
    }
  }

\begin{document}
  \nocite{MEMSnet,WikiMEMS,wilde,markey}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

`*` `biblatex` distinguishes between `name`s, `field`s and `list`s. For example, `author` is a `name`, `series` a `field` and `organization` a `list`. There are different macros to check for equality between those fields. You cannot use `\iffieldequalstr` to check whether a `name` equals a given string. Since names are arguably the most complex part of what `biblatex` has to deal with they also have the most complicated identity conditions. After all one would not want the name given in a `.bib` file as `Peter Smith` to match the string `Smith`, but you would want both `Peter Smith` and `Smith, Peter` to match `Peter Smith` since both input formats are equally valid in the `.bib` file. So `biblatex` accepts only comparing against macros that are supposed to already include the proper name syntax as given in the `.bbl` file. In our case `{}{{{}{Wikipedia}{W.}{}{}{}{}{}{}}}`.

---

On a different note. In this case it might be quite apt do define a dedicated entry type (one might like to call it `@wiki`) for this task.

As you seem to use BibTeX as backend and not the (in my opinion at least) far superior biber, let us first explore our possibilities with BibTeX and then go on to see how much better we can do with biber.

`biblatex` by default has six entry types for custom modifications: these are `customa` to `customf`.
Here we will use `customa`.

From now on, if you want to cite a wiki entry, do not use `@online`/`@electronic`, but `@customa`.

```
@customa{WikiMEMS,
  author = {Wikipedia},
  title = {Microelectromechanical systems},
  url = {http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microelectromechanical_systems},
  organization = {Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia},
  date = {2013-11-28},
  urldate = {2013-12-25},
}
```

The fields are as expected; note that `urldate` takes the date the resource was last accessed and `date` the date the resource was last modified, just as one would expect.

Once again we have

```
\NewBibliographyString{lastmodified}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  lastmodified = {last modified}
}
```

Finally we have the driver, the piece of code that prints the bibliography entry

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{customa}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\addperiod\addspace}%or \setunit{\adddot\addspace}
  \iffieldundef{year}%
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{\bibstring{lastmodified}\space\usebibmacro{date}}}%
  \setunit{\adddot\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \setunit{\adddot\addspace}%
  \printlist{language}%
  \setunit{\adddot\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \setunit{\adddot\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \setunit{\adddot\addspace}%
  \printfield{version}%
  \setunit{\adddot\addspace}%
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printlist{organization}%
  \setunit{\adddot\addspace}%
  \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}
    {\usebibmacro{eprint}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{url+urldate}%
  \setunit{\adddot\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{related}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}
```

This driver is almost a one-to-one copy of `ieee.bbx`'s `@online` driver, save for a slight modification in the `date` area to print "last modified".

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=ieee,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ELECTRONIC{MEMSnet,
  title = {What is {MEMS}?},
  organization = {MEMSnet},
  url = {http://www.memsnet.org/mems/what_is.html},
  urldate = {2013-12-01},
}

@customa{WikiMEMS,
  author = {Wikipedia},
  title = {Microelectromechanical systems},
  url = {http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microelectromechanical_systems},
  organization = {Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia},
  date = {2013-11-28},
  urldate = {2013-12-25},
}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\xpatchbibdriver{online}
  {\printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{date}}}
  {\iffieldundef{year}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{date}}}}
  {}
  {\typeout{There was an error patching biblatex-ieee (ieee.bbx's @online driver)}}

\NewBibliographyString{lastmodified}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  lastmodified = {last modified}
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{customa}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\addperiod\addspace}%or \setunit{\adddot\addspace}
  \iffieldundef{year}%
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{\bibstring{lastmodified}\space\usebibmacro{date}}}%
  \setunit{\adddot\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \setunit{\adddot\addspace}%
  \printlist{language}%
  \setunit{\adddot\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \setunit{\adddot\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \setunit{\adddot\addspace}%
  \printfield{version}%
  \setunit{\adddot\addspace}%
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printlist{organization}%
  \setunit{\adddot\addspace}%
  \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}
    {\usebibmacro{eprint}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{url+urldate}%
  \setunit{\adddot\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{related}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{MEMSnet,WikiMEMS,wilde,markey}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

---

With `biber` we can instead define a new type `@wiki` just by defining the driver as above with `wiki`

```
\NewBibliographyString{lastmodified}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  lastmodified = {last modified}
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{wiki}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\addperiod\addspace}%or \setunit{\adddot\addspace}
  \iffieldundef{year}%
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{\bibstring{lastmodified}\space\usebibmacro{date}}}%
  \setunit{\adddot\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \setunit{\adddot\addspace}%
  \printlist{language}%
  \setunit{\adddot\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \setunit{\adddot\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \setunit{\adddot\addspace}%
  \printfield{version}%
  \setunit{\adddot\addspace}%
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printlist{organization}%
  \setunit{\adddot\addspace}%
  \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}
    {\usebibmacro{eprint}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{url+urldate}%
  \setunit{\adddot\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{related}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}
```

The `.bib` file as expected

```
@wiki{WikiMEMS,
  author = {Wikipedia},
  title = {Microelectromechanical systems},
  url = {http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microelectromechanical_systems},
  organization = {Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia},
  date = {2013-11-28},
  urldate = {2013-12-25},
}
```

The MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=ieee,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ELECTRONIC{MEMSnet,
  title = {What is {MEMS}?},
  organization = {MEMSnet},
  url = {http://www.memsnet.org/mems/what_is.html},
  urldate = {2013-12-01},
}

@wiki{WikiMEMS,
  author = {Wikipedia},
  title = {Microelectromechanical systems},
  url = {http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microelectromechanical_systems},
  organization = {Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia},
  date = {2013-11-28},
  urldate = {2013-12-25},
}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\xpatchbibdriver{online}
  {\printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{date}}}
  {\iffieldundef{year}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{date}}}}
  {}
  {\typeout{There was an error patching biblatex-ieee (ieee.bbx's @online driver)}}

\NewBibliographyString{lastmodified}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  lastmodified = {last modified}
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{wiki}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\addperiod\addspace}%or \setunit{\adddot\addspace}
  \iffieldundef{year}%
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{\bibstring{lastmodified}\space\usebibmacro{date}}}%
  \setunit{\adddot\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \setunit{\adddot\addspace}%
  \printlist{language}%
  \setunit{\adddot\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \setunit{\adddot\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \setunit{\adddot\addspace}%
  \printfield{version}%
  \setunit{\adddot\addspace}%
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printlist{organization}%
  \setunit{\adddot\addspace}%
  \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}
    {\usebibmacro{eprint}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{url+urldate}%
  \setunit{\adddot\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{related}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{MEMSnet,WikiMEMS,wilde,markey}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Both MWEs above yield
[image]

---

With biber one could now very easily add custom fields; for example a licence field, describing the terms of use of the `@wiki` entry. This can be done as described in [How to include price in bibliography?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/150404/35864).