# How can I dynamically modify inherited crossref'd values in BibLaTeX/Biber?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

Suppose I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
    @online {page1,
        crossref = "mysite",
        title = "Page 1",
        url = "http://www.example.com/page1.html"
    }

    @online {page2,
        crossref = "mysite",
        title = "Page 2",
        url = "http://www.example.com/page2.html"
    }

    @online {mysite,
        title = "My Website Home",
        author = "John Doe",
        date = "2016-01-01",
        url = "http://www.example.com/",
        organization = "My Website"
    }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{mysite}, \cite{page1}, \cite{page2}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

As you can see, I have two webpages, `page1` and `page2` which are `crossref`'d from the entry `mysite`. This is nice, but unfortunately it requires me to copy the URL each time I add a new page. Now, for such a trivial example, it isn't too much of a hassle, but it's a pain for large bibliographies, and can be error prone. I set about trying to figure out a way to fix this. First, I added the following mapping code to the header:

```
...
\DeclareDriverSourcemap{
    \map[overwrite]{
      \pertype{online}
      \step[fieldsource=webpage]
      \step[fieldset=url, origfieldval, append]
    }
}
...
```

Then, I modified the two entries which reference `mysite` like so:

```
...
@online {page1,
    crossref = "mysite",
    title = "Page 1",
    webpage = "page1.html"
}

@online {page2,
    crossref = "mysite",
    title = "Page 2",
    webpage = "page2.html"
}
...
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. While it does put the contents of the `webpage` field into the `url` field, it does not *append* the content of the former to the inherited URL. I'm at a loss as to what the matter is. Is there some way to make BibLaTeX use inherited values when doing maps?

Comment: @Mico well, even if that's true, it doesn't appear to make a difference, it still doesn't work. But I'll update the question in any case

Comment: I guess that is because sourcemapping is one of the first steps Biber does when processing the `.bib` file. While inheritance comes later. So when your sourcemap is executed inheritance has not taken place.

Comment: Imho `url` should contain an `url`. Why don't you change the macros so that the url is printed as `url`+ `webpage`?

Comment: @moewe is correct - sourcemapping is the very first thing that happens, otherwise you wouldn't know what exactly you were changing.

Comment: (I agree with Ulrike here, and can't disagree with PLK or moewe; but just trying to offer another workaround.) If you want to save yourself some typing, you could do `@string{mywww = "http://www.example.com"}` and then `url = mywww` in the entries. Your sourcemapping would work fine then.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: oh, I see: so just change the ``\DeclareFieldFormat`` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to suggestions from the comments, I found a workable solution to the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\DeclareDriverSourcemap{
    \map[overwrite]{
      \pertype{online}
      \step[fieldsource=webpage]
      \step[fieldset=verba, origfieldval]
    }
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\mkbibacro{URL}\addcolon\space\nolinkurl{#1\thefield{verba}}}


\begin{filecontents}{plainurl.bib}
    @online {page1,
        crossref = "mysite",
        title = "Page 1",
        webpage = "page1.html"
    }

    @online {page2,
        crossref = "mysite",
        title = "Page 2",
        webpage = "page2.html"
    }

    @online {mysite,
        title = "My Website Home",
        author = "John Doe",
        date = "2016-01-01",
        url = "http://www.example.com/",
        organization = "My Website"
    }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{plainurl.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{mysite}, \cite{page1}, \cite{page2}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Instead of trying to dynamically modify the URL field, what I've instead done is changed the `DeclareFieldFormat` command for the `url` field. Also, I couldn't get it to work with `\thefield{webpage}` so I first mapped the field `webpage` to `verba` and then used that. Also, it's important to note that `hyperref` is required for this to work, otherwise the input to the `\url` command will be treated like verbatim text.

Comment: If you wanted to use `\thefield{webpage}`, you would have to declare the field with Biber beforehand using a `.dbx` file. See [the third part of my answer here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/163396/35864) for example.

Comment: You might want to restrict the declaration of the field format by means of the optional argument: `\DeclareFieldFormat[online]{...}`.