# Add a custom .bib entry to bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I would like to add the total number of bookpages e.g. ", 543 S." to every bibliography entry (if that field is filled). I have named the .bib-field "nop"

For example: "PAIL, R. (2017) [...] Springer Spektrum, 217–257, 543 S."

instead of "PAIL, R. (2017) [...] Springer Spektrum, 217–257.".

I have excluded many lines of the actual bibliography design as I don't think it is necessary here. The code is:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear-ibid, giveninits=true, uniquelist=false, 
backend=biber, natbib=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Quellen.bib}

\begin{document}
\parencite[220]{Pail.2017}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and

```
@book{Pail.2017,
 author = {Pail, Roland},
 title = {Globale Schwerefeldmodellierung am Beispiel von GOCE},
 pages = {217--257},
 booktitle = {Erdmessung und Satellitengeod{\"a}sie},
 year = {2017},
 address = {Berlin}
 nop = {543}
}
```

Comment: There is no field `nop`, but there is `pagetotal` for a similar purpose. `pagetotal` is however only available for the types `@book`, `@collection`, `@manual`, `@report` since it holds the total number of pages of a single work. The total number of pages of a `@incollection`, `@inbook` or `@article` can be calculated from the `pages` field. In your example the `pagetotal` would refer to the enclosing `@collection` work while `pages` would refer to the `@incollection`. I don't think `pagetotal` makes a lot of sense here.

Comment: I have added "nop={543}" by myself (using Citavi) as it did not show up in the .bib file until then. I just used this incollection as an example - does not make much sense, you're right. In the case of a book - how could I add that field to the bibliography?

Comment: Use `pagetotal`

Comment: For people coming here looking to find out how to add a new field that isn't yet known to the data model, have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/163303/35864

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field you are looking for is `pagetotal`. `pagetotal` holds the total number of pages of a work. The standard styles only print `pagetotal` for `@book`-like stand-alone works (`@book`, `@collection`, `@manual`, `@thesis`, ...).

For example from [`biblatex-examples.bib`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/bibtex/bib/biblatex/biblatex-examples.bib)

```
@book{companion,
  author       = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and Samarin, Alexander},
  title        = {The {LaTeX} Companion},
  date         = 1994,
  edition      = 1,
  publisher    = {Addison-Wesley},
  location     = {Reading, Mass.},
  pagetotal    = 528,
}
```

---

If you insist on a comma before the `pagetotal`, you will need to patch the bibdrivers.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear-ibid, giveninits=true, uniquelist=false, 
backend=biber, natbib=true]{biblatex}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\newcommand*{\commapagetotal}[1]{%
  \xpatchbibdriver{#1}
    {\newunit\printfield{pagetotal}}
    {\setunit{\addcomma\space}\printfield{pagetotal}}
    {}{}}
\forcsvlist{\commapagetotal}{book,booklet,collection,manual,proceedings,report,thesis}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\parencite{companion}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

*The original question had an `@incolletion` entry as example. There things are a bit more tricky...*

For works like `@inbook`, `@incollection` and `@article` the field is not used because the total number of pages can be easily calculated from the `pages` field.

There is a slight semantic quirk of filling the `pagetotal` field of a `@in...` type work with the total number of pages of the enclosing work, but a similar thing happens to `editor` or `isbn`, so...

You need to patch the driver of `@incollection` to include `pagetotal`. This can be done with `xpatch`'s `\xpatchbibdriver`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear-ibid, giveninits=true, uniquelist=false, 
backend=biber, natbib=true]{biblatex}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\newcommand*{\addpagetotalto}[1]{%
  \xpatchbibdriver{#1}
    {\usebibmacro{chapter+pages}}
    {\usebibmacro{chapter+pages}\newunit\printfield{pagetotal}}
    {}{}}
\forcsvlist{\addpagetotalto}{inbook,incollection,inproceedings}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{Pail.2017,
 author    = {Pail, Roland},
 title     = {Globale Schwerefeldmodellierung am Beispiel von GOCE},
 pages     = {217--257},
 publisher = {Springer Spektrum},
 editor    = {Rummel, Reinhard and Freeden, Willi},
 booktitle = {Erdmessung und Satellitengeodäsie},
 year      = {2017},
 address   = {Berlin},
 pagetotal = 543,
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\parencite[220]{Pail.2017}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

I personally think the information is superfluous, but if you like it...

Comment: I get what you mean and have renamed the Citavi entry now and changed it from nop to pagetotal. How can I get (in this case) "217-257, 543 S." instead of "217-257. 543 S."?

Comment: @Vivi In a `@book` entry you will usually not have a `pages` field (after all a `@book` is the *entire* book), so there is no '217-257'.

Comment: I am sorry, my bib-example was not too clever. Let's just assume this is a book. Then it would be "...Springer Spektrum. 543 S." But I need to have it this way: "...Springer Spektrum, 543 S."

Comment: @Vivi That depends. The punctuation before `pagetotal` is the standard unit punctuation which normally is a full stop/period. That could be changed to a comma everywhere with `\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}`, but that is probably not what you want since it affects many more places. If you only want to change the punctuation before `pagetotal` you need to patch the drivers. ...

Comment: Alright, I'll have to leave it this way then. Patching the drivers sounds far too complicated as I am only a beginner and due date is tomorrow

Comment: @Vivi Ohh, good luck. See the edit for the patch.