# Customising Journalsubtitle

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

I'm wondering if you can use the journalsubtitle like a titleaddon, since there's no addon option for journaltitles, right?

I have customised the style for addontitles, so that they serve as a translation for the original title, s. example: green = right, red = wrong

[image: green = right, red = wrong]

Now I would like the journalsubtitle to be usable the exact same way, omitting a dot [translated title here] add dot

Is there a way to do that?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  a4paper,
  headings=standardclasses,
  numbers=noenddot
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=2.50cm, right=2.50cm, top=2.50cm, bottom=2.00cm, footskip=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[main=ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[ngerman]{isodate}
\usepackage[ngerman]{datetime}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=ext-authoryear,
  sorting=nyvt,
  maxnames=25
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{jobname.bib}

% editor and et al. spelling
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
  andothers = {et al\adddot},
  byeditor    = {Hg\adddotspace von},
  editor    = {Hg\adddot},
  editors   = {Hg\adddot},
  urlseen = {letzter Abruf},
}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite=false]{
      \pertype{article}
      \step[fieldsource=entrysubtype, match=\regexp{\Anewspaper\Z}, final]
      \step[fieldsource=journal, final]
      \step[fieldset=author, origfieldval, final]
      \step[fieldsource=author, match=\regexp{\A(.*)\Z}, replace=\regexp{\{$1\}}]
      \step[fieldset=author+an, fieldvalue={1=journalauthor}]
      \step[fieldset=options, fieldvalue={journalauthor}]
    }
  }
}

\newtoggle{bbx@journalauthor}
\DeclareEntryOption[boolean]{journalauthor}[true]{%
\settoggle{bbx@journalauthor}{#1}}

\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{%
  \ifitemannotation{journalauthor}
    {\mkbibemph{#1}}
    {\textsc{#1}}}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}


% no period after addon titles
\renewcommand*{\titleaddonpunct}{\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat{titleaddon}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\DeclareFieldAlias{booktitleaddon}{titleaddon}
\DeclareFieldAlias{maintitleaddon}{titleaddon}

\newbibmacro{online:editor+maintitle}{% organization in front of maintitle
  \printlist{organization}%
  \clearlist{organization}%
  \setunit*{\addcolon\space}%
  \printnames{editor}%
  \setunit*{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{maintitle}}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibdriver{online}
  {\usebibmacro{byeditor+others}}
  {\usebibmacro{online:editor+maintitle}}
  {}{}
\xpatchbibmacro{editorstrg}{\bibstring}{\bibcpstring}{}{}
\xpatchbibmacro{editorstrg}{\bibstring}{\bibcpstring}{}{}

\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \iftoggle{bbx@journalauthor}
    {}
    {\printtext{%
     \bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

\DeclareNameAlias{ineditor}{sortname}

\renewcommand*{\volnumdelim}{\addcomma\space}

% set articles as per IOA
\DeclareListWrapperFormat[article]{parenlocation}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareListAlias{parenlocation}{location}
\renewbibmacro*{journal}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    (test {\iffieldundef{journaltitle}}
     and
     test {\iffieldundef{journalsubtitle}})
    or
    togl {bbx@journalauthor}
  }
    {\ifboolexpr{
       togl {bbx@journalauthor}
       and
       test {\iffieldequalstr{entrysubtype}{newspaper}}
     }
       {\printlist{location}}
       {}}
    {\printtext[journaltitle]{%
       \printfield[titlecase]{journaltitle}%
       \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
       \printfield[titlecase]{journalsubtitle}}%
     \iffieldequalstr{entrysubtype}{newspaper}
       {\setunit{\addspace}%
        \printlist[parenlocation]{location}}
       {}}}

\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:ifmergeddate}
    {}
    {\printtext[issuedate]{%
       \printdate}}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{issue}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}}

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\jourvoldelim}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\setunit*{\jourserdelim}%
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\servoldelim}}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
  \setunit{\volnumdatedelim}%
  \iftoggle{bbx@journalauthor}
    {}
    {}
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit}


\begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}
@article{Ueda.2005,
 title = {Heian-ky\={o} no seiritsu to higashiajia},
 titleaddon = {Die Errichtung von Heian-ky\={o} und Ostasien},
 journaltitle = {Kodai higashi ajia no rekishi to bunka},
 journalsubtitle = {Geschichte und Kultur im ostasiatischen Altertum},
 author = {Ueda, Masaaki},
 year = {2005},
 volume = {122},
 publisher = {Higashiajia no kodai bunka kodai-gaku kenky\={u}-jo},
 location = {Japan},
 pages = {2-8},
 Catalogue-Link* = {http://iss.ndl.go.jp/books/R000000004-I7260043-00}
}

 @incollection{Ki.1957,
 author = {Ki, Tsurayuki},
 title = {Tosa Nikki},
 titleaddon = {Das Tagebuch von Tosa},
 pages = {5--81},
 publisher = {{Iwanami Shoten}},
 maintitle = {Nihon Koten Bungaku Taikei},
 maintitleaddon = {Japanische klassische Literatur},
 editor = {Suzuki, Tomotar\={o} and Kawaguchi, Hisao and End\={o}, Yoshimoto and Nishishita, Tsunekazu},
 booktitle = {Tosa Nikki. Kager\={o} Nikki. Izumi Shikibu Nikki. Sarashina Nikki},
 year = {1957},
 location = {T\={o}ky\={o}},
 volume = {20},
 keywords = {primary}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={Literaturverzeichnis}]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be possibly to modify the macros to format the `journalsubtitle` like a (fictitious) `journaltitleaddon`, but it appears to be much cleaner and nicer to me to just define `journaltitleaddon`.

This requires a new datamodel (`.dbx`) file to register the new field and the addition of `\setunit{\titleaddonpunct}%`and `\printfield{journaltitleaddon}%` to `\renewbibmacro*{journal}` in order to print it. Compare also [Add field "tome" to biblatex entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/163303/35864).

```
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  a4paper,
  headings=standardclasses,
  numbers=noenddot
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[main=ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{journaltitleaddon.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=literal]{
  journaltitleaddon}

\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[article,periodical]{
  journaltitleaddon}
\end{filecontents}


\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  datamodel=journaltitleaddon,
  style=ext-authoryear,
  sorting=nyvt,
  maxnames=25
]{biblatex}


% editor and et al. spelling
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
  andothers = {et al\adddot},
  byeditor  = {Hg\adddotspace von},
  editor    = {Hg\adddot},
  editors   = {Hg\adddot},
  urlseen   = {letzter Abruf},
}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite=false]{
      \pertype{article}
      \step[fieldsource=entrysubtype, match=\regexp{\Anewspaper\Z}, final]
      \step[fieldsource=journal, final]
      \step[fieldset=author, origfieldval, final]
      \step[fieldsource=author, match=\regexp{\A(.*)\Z}, replace=\regexp{\{$1\}}]
      \step[fieldset=author+an, fieldvalue={1=journalauthor}]
      \step[fieldset=options, fieldvalue={journalauthor}]
    }
  }
}

\newtoggle{bbx@journalauthor}
\DeclareEntryOption[boolean]{journalauthor}[true]{%
\settoggle{bbx@journalauthor}{#1}}

\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{%
  \ifitemannotation{journalauthor}
    {\mkbibemph{#1}}
    {\textsc{#1}}}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}


% no period after addon titles
\renewcommand*{\titleaddonpunct}{\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat{titleaddon}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\DeclareFieldAlias{booktitleaddon}{titleaddon}
\DeclareFieldAlias{maintitleaddon}{titleaddon}
\DeclareFieldAlias{journaltitleaddon}{titleaddon}

\newbibmacro{online:editor+maintitle}{% organization in front of maintitle
  \printlist{organization}%
  \clearlist{organization}%
  \setunit*{\addcolon\space}%
  \printnames{editor}%
  \setunit*{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{maintitle}}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibdriver{online}
  {\usebibmacro{byeditor+others}}
  {\usebibmacro{online:editor+maintitle}}
  {}{}
\xpatchbibmacro{editorstrg}{\bibstring}{\bibcpstring}{}{}
\xpatchbibmacro{editorstrg}{\bibstring}{\bibcpstring}{}{}

\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \iftoggle{bbx@journalauthor}
    {}
    {\printtext{%
     \bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

\DeclareNameAlias{ineditor}{sortname}

\renewcommand*{\volnumdelim}{\addcomma\space}

% set articles as per IOA
\DeclareListWrapperFormat[article]{parenlocation}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareListAlias{parenlocation}{location}
\renewbibmacro*{journal}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    (test {\iffieldundef{journaltitle}}
     and
     test {\iffieldundef{journalsubtitle}})
    or
    togl {bbx@journalauthor}
  }
    {\ifboolexpr{
       togl {bbx@journalauthor}
       and
       test {\iffieldequalstr{entrysubtype}{newspaper}}
     }
       {\printlist{location}}
       {}}
    {\printtext[journaltitle]{%
       \printfield[titlecase]{journaltitle}%
       \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
       \printfield[titlecase]{journalsubtitle}}%
     \setunit{\titleaddonpunct}%
     \printfield{journaltitleaddon}%
     \iffieldequalstr{entrysubtype}{newspaper}
       {\setunit{\addspace}%
        \printlist[parenlocation]{location}}
       {}}}

\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:ifmergeddate}
    {}
    {\printtext[issuedate]{%
       \printdate}}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{issue}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}}

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\jourvoldelim}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\setunit*{\jourserdelim}%
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\servoldelim}}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
  \setunit{\volnumdatedelim}%
  \iftoggle{bbx@journalauthor}
    {}
    {}
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Ueda.2005,
 title             = {Heian-ky\={o} no seiritsu to higashiajia},
 titleaddon        = {Die Errichtung von Heian-ky\={o} und Ostasien},
 journaltitle      = {Kodai higashi ajia no rekishi to bunka},
 journaltitleaddon = {Geschichte und Kultur im ostasiatischen Altertum},
 author            = {Ueda, Masaaki},
 year              = {2005},
 volume            = {122},
 publisher         = {Higashiajia no kodai bunka kodai-gaku kenky\={u}-jo},
 location          = {Japan},
 pages             = {2-8},
 Catalogue-Link*   = {http://iss.ndl.go.jp/books/R000000004-I7260043-00}
}

 @incollection{Ki.1957,
 author         = {Ki, Tsurayuki},
 title          = {Tosa Nikki},
 titleaddon     = {Das Tagebuch von Tosa},
 pages          = {5--81},
 publisher      = {{Iwanami Shoten}},
 maintitle      = {Nihon Koten Bungaku Taikei},
 maintitleaddon = {Japanische klassische Literatur},
 editor         = {Suzuki, Tomotar\={o} and Kawaguchi, Hisao
                   and End\={o}, Yoshimoto and Nishishita, Tsunekazu},
 booktitle      = {Tosa Nikki. Kager\={o} Nikki. Izumi Shikibu Nikki. Sarashina Nikki},
 year           = {1957},
 location       = {T\={o}ky\={o}},
 volume         = {20},
 keywords       = {primary}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={Literaturverzeichnis}]
\end{document}
```

[image: Ueda, Masaaki (2005): „Heian-kyo no seiritsu to higashiajia“ [Die Errichtung von Heian-kyo und Ostasien]. In: Kodai higashi ajia no rekishi to bunka [Geschichte und Kultur im ostasiatischen Altertum] 122, S. 2–8.]

Comment: thank you very much for the reply! I am sorry for the follow-up-question - I have tried to figure out the "tome" tutorial, however I am not sure what the dbx file should contain and where i should save it, for your example to work :)

Comment: @user168390 In the MWE I posted the `.dbx` file will be created automatically be the `\begin{filecontents}{journaltitleaddon.dbx}...\end{filecontents}`. If you don't want to carry around the `filecontents` in your actual document, just copy the *contents* of the environment to a file called `journaltitleaddon.dbx` and place it somewhere LaTeX can find it (LaTeX will definitely be able to find the file if you put it in the same folder as your main `.tex` document, for more advanced globally available placement see https://texfaq.org/FAQ-inst-wlcf and links).

Comment: thank you it worked perfectly fine! :)