# How to cite specific custom field with BibLaTeX?

Tags: biblatex, citing, biblatex-philosophy

I am working on a document commenting another paper (Gödels incompleteness theorems). Therefore, I need two lists of bibliographies, one is mine and one the one from the other paper.

The other paper is quite old and uses different style'd citations. I want to keep the original paper as much as possible, so I want to create a custom field like:

```
@book{taocp1,
    keywords={own},
    author="Donald Ervin Knuth",
    title="The Art of Computer Programming, Volume 1",
    year=1968,
    isbn="978-0-201-89683-1"
}


@article{hilbertschebeweistheorie,
    keywords={goedel},
    goedeltitle={J.~v.~\so{Neumann}, Zur \so{Hilbert}schen Beweistheorie, Math. Zeitschr. 26, 1927.},
    year=1927,
    author="John von Neumann",
    title="Zur \so{Hilbert}schen Beweistheorie",
    journal="Mathematische Zeitschrift",
    number=26
}
```

Now, I know that I can have two bibliographies with things like

```
\printbibliography[keyword={own}] % Citations with keyword "own"
\printbibliography[keyword={goedel}] % Citations with keyword "goedel"
```

This works fine. But I need to cite the "goedeltitle" field to get the original string used for citing the work (but still have it cited normally in the second bibliography).

I tried

```
\citefield{hilbertschebeweistheorie}{goedeltitle}
```

and this gets the work cited in the second bibliography. But the text where goedeltitle is supposed to be only becomes **hilbertschebeweistheorie** in the PDF.

I'm using this command to load biblatex:

```
\usepackage[
    citestyle=authortitle-ibid,
    isbn=true,
    url=true,
    backref=true,
    backrefstyle=none,
    pagetracker=true,
    maxbibnames=50,
    defernumbers=true,
    maxcitenames=10,
    backend=bibtex,
    urldate=comp,
    dateabbrev=false,
    sorting=nty,
    ibidtracker=true
]{biblatex}
\bibliography{literatur.bib}
```

Comment: If you want to use a field that is not part of the standard data model (as documented in the `biblatex` manual), you need to declare this field before you can use it. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/163303/35864 for more details.

Comment: Did the linked answer help you or do you need more specific help to get your example going?

Comment: I voted to close this question as a duplicate of the 'tome' question. If you can't get the solution(s) explained there to work, please edit the question to explain what you did and how it did not work for you and give me a ping. I will then vote to reopen.