# Making a new Biblatex datatype

Tags: biblatex

I am currently in the process of modifying one biblatex style to conform to another, and that includes adding a new datatype. I have added the code below to my style.bbx

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[datatype]{title}{{#1}\addperiod}
\DeclareFieldFormat[datatype]{foo}{{#1}\addperiod}
\DeclareFieldFormat[datatype]{bar}{#1}
```

When using `\DeclareBibliographyDriver{datatype}`, `\printfield{title}` is the only one that prints anything. `\printfield{foo}` and `\printfield{bar}` do not produce anything.

Changing foo to another field already in use (such as journaltitle) seems to work, but I'd like to avoid a hacky solution like that if possible.

Comment: If you want a new data type with new fields you need to declare the new fields/type in a data model file. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/175776/35864 (which would be a good duplicate) and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/163303/35864 (for a few alternatives).

Comment: @moewe Thank you so much, this has ended a few months of confusion. I ended up referring to the second one and mapping fields to existing ones.

Comment: OK, do you think we can close this as a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/163303/35864 then?

Comment: Yes, that should be fine.