# print bibliography fields selectively with biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I would like to show the rank of the journal in just one of the bibliographies I show in the document. That is, I need to selectively print a field of the bibliography item. `note` is the field I have chosen to do so. The only thing I came up with is to do something similar to what I do for the bold name but for the note field. However, I did not succeed because I can not understand properly the whole section of "Data Annotations" from `biblatex` manual.

Here is a MWE of what I have done so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=numeric-comp,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{file.bib}
@article{gillies,
  author       = {Gillies, Alexander},
  author+an = {1=highlight},
  title        = {Herder and the Preparation of {Goethe's} Idea of World Literature},
  journaltitle = {Publications of the English Goethe Society},
  date         = {1933},
%  date+an      = {=attributed},
  series       = {newseries},
  volume       = {9},
%  volume+an    = {=attributed},
  pages        = {46-67},
  note = {Q1},
  note+an={2=rank}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{file.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{refsection}
%comandos para resaltarme como autor en negrita en mis publicaciones
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamegiven}[1]{%
  \ifitemannotation{highlight}
    {\textbf{#1}}
    {#1}}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{%
  \ifitemannotation{highlight}
    {\textbf{#1}}
    {#1}}

\nocite{gillies}

\printbibliography    
    
 \end{refsection}

\nocite{gillies}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

If someone knows how to achieve my purpose either employing the data attributes from `biblatex` or any other method, they are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a slightly different approach. I'd define a new field with a more semantic name for what you want here instead of `note`. Then you can selectively inject code to print the new field in the bibliography where you want to see the field.

For the new field we need a data model file (`.dbx`), see also [Add field "tome" to biblatex entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/163303/35864).

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents*}{rank.dbx}
\ProvidesFile{rank.dbx}[2020/07/05 add rank field]

\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{rank}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{rank}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=numeric-comp,
  datamodel=rank,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{gillies,
  author       = {Gillies, Alexander},
  author+an    = {1=highlight},
  title        = {Herder and the Preparation of {Goethe's} Idea of World Literature},
  journaltitle = {Publications of the English Goethe Society},
  date         = {1933},
  series       = {newseries},
  volume       = {9},
  pages        = {46-67},
  rank         = {Q1},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{refsection}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibcompletename}[1]{%
  \ifitemannotation{highlight}
    {\textbf{#1}}
    {#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{\newunit\newblock\printfield{rank}\finentry}

\nocite{gillies}
\printbibliography
\end{refsection}


\nocite{gillies}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Alexander Gillies. “Herder and the Preparation of Goethe’s Idea of World Literature”. In: Publications of the English Goethe Society. New ser. 9 (1933), pp. 46–67. Q1.//Alexander Gillies. “Herder and the Preparation of Goethe’s Idea of World Literature”. In: Publications of the English Goethe Society. New ser. 9 (1933), pp. 46–67.]

---

I don't quite feel that field annotations are the best solution here, but it can be done.  We need to define a few new macros because `\AtEveryBibitem` and `\AtBeginBibliography` usually act globally and are only allowed in the preamble.

The idea is to remove all note fields with `rank` annotation in the second bibliography.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=numeric-comp,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd*{\LocalAtBeginBibliography}{\appto\blx@hook@bibinit}
\newrobustcmd*{\LocalAtEveryBibitem}{\appto\blx@hook@bibitem}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{gillies,
  author       = {Gillies, Alexander},
  author+an    = {1=highlight},
  title        = {Herder and the Preparation of {Goethe's} Idea of World Literature},
  journaltitle = {Publications of the English Goethe Society},
  date         = {1933},
  series       = {newseries},
  volume       = {9},
  pages        = {46-67},
  note         = {Q1},
  note+an      = {=rank},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{refsection}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibcompletename}[1]{%
  \ifitemannotation{highlight}
    {\textbf{#1}}
    {#1}}

\nocite{gillies}
\printbibliography
\end{refsection}

\LocalAtBeginBibliography{%
  \LocalAtEveryBibitem{%
    \iffieldannotation[note]{rank}
      {\clearfield{note}}
      {}}}
\nocite{gillies}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Alexander Gillies. “Herder and the Preparation of Goethe’s Idea of World Literature”. In: Publications of the English Goethe Society. New ser. 9 (1933). Q1, pp. 46–67.//Alexander Gillies. “Herder and the Preparation of Goethe’s Idea of World Literature”. In: Publications of the English Goethe Society. New ser. 9 (1933), pp. 46–67.]

---

Note that I simplified the code for the bold name by using the new `\mkbibcompletename`, which applies to the complete name and not only name parts like `\mkbibnamefamily` and `\mkbibnamegiven`.

Comment: Simply a great answer, thanks.