# How to include 'impact factor' in the bibliography with the respective reference

Tags: biblatex, bibliographystyle, authoryear

In my thesis, I have to print the list of publications along with the corresponding impact factor of the journal. While using `authoryear` style of `biblatex` package, how can we customize it to print the impact factor as well?

Should we define a new field, or are there any feasible solutions for achieving it? I am sharing what I already have modified in the preamble of my file -

```
\usepackage[bibstyle=authoryear,
citestyle=phys,
backend=biber,
defernumbers=true,
natbib=true,
%biblabel=brackets,
isbn=false,
maxbibnames=10,
minbibnames=5,
giveninits=true,
hyperref=true,
%urldate=false,
sorting=none
]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\textbf{#1}\addcomma\space} % Bolds volume of citation and adds comma after volume
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1} % No prefix for the "pages" field in the bibliography
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1}  % Remove quotes from journal title

%Suppress 'number' preceeding the vol. in bibliography;
\AtEveryBibitem{%
    \clearfield{number}}
%
%Suppress 'month' followed by year in bibliography;
\AtEveryBibitem{%
    \clearfield{month}}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first} % Lists all authors with last name first
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcomma\addspace} % Removes period after year in bibliography
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{\addspace}% want a comma between last name and initials
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addcomma\addspace}% want a space but no comma between names
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addcomma\addspace\bibstring{and}\space}% want a space but no comma between penultimate name and 'and' followed by final name
\DeclareSourcemap{% Ignores urldates
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=urldate, null]
    }
  }
}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchbibmacro{name:andothers}{% maked the ``et al'' italicized in the bibliography
\bibstring{andothers}%
}{%
\bibstring[\emph]{andothers}%
}{}{}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{% Removes "In" from bibliography entries
\ifentrytype{article}{}{%
\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{#1.}% from karlkoeller's answer

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
    {\printfield[labelnumberwidth]{labelnumber}}
    {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\itemindent}{\labelwidth}%
      \addtolength{\itemindent}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
    \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}
```

A possible solution was to write manually the *impact factor* of each journal in the my-ref.bib file and letting it to print at the end. But it interrupts the `hyperref` which is required in the bibliography, and the link is corrupted.

I tried to definine a new field in `biblatex` as follows -

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{impactfactor}{\mkbibparens{IF: #1}} % New format for impact factor
% Define a new bibmacro to print impact factor
\newbibmacro*{impactfactor}{%
  \printfield{impactfactor}%
}
```

But that also didn't work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I want to add 'impact factor' in my bibliography list. How to do that using authoryear style in biblatex.

Comment: Welcome. // Almost always we need to try posted code, i.e. copy and compile it. Your code at the moment can't compile unfortunately. // Please add the missing parts, starting with `\documentclass`, ending with `end{document}`, discarding all lines not needed, AND still showing your problem. Including a screenshot of the result may also help. Perhaps you need to include commandline actions as well. // Is impact factor an established term or is it an idea?

Comment: New fields need to be declared to `biblatex` first. They cannot be used just like that. You also need to make sure the field is actually printed by adding code to a used bibmacro or driver. It is not enough to define an eponymous bibmacro. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/163303/35864 for the several ways you can get hold of a new field.

Comment: Any news here? I feel that this is basically a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/163303/35864, which shows how to add a new field to the output.