# Unable to Call "Publisher" or "Location" in Biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I am trying to add the final touches to a customisation of Biblatex. However, for `book` I am unable to call `publisher` or `location`. I am using

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
    \printnames{author}%
\   \newblock
    \printtext[parens]{\printfield{year}}\addperiod%
\   \newblock
    \printfield{title}%
\   \newblock
    \printfield{edition}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \printfield{publisher}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \printfield{location}%
}
```

with the bibtem

```
@book{B:random-graphs,
    location = {{Cambridge}},
    title = {Random {{Graphs}}},
    edition = {2},
    series = {Cambridge Studies in Advanced Mathematics},
    publisher = {{Cambridge University Press}},
    date = {2001},
    author = {Bollob{\'a}s, B{\'e}la},
    doi = {10.1017/CBO9780511814068}
}
```

This outputs the following.
[image: <<output>>]

I don't understand why the `\printfield{publisher}` and `\printfield{location}` lines don't make this as follows:

> B. Bollobas (2001). *Random Graphs* 2nd ed. Cambridge University Press Cambridge

Assistance would be most appreciated! :)

Comment: Both the `publisher` and `location` fields are not actually `field`s in the sense of `biblatex`'s data model, they are `list`s and must be printed with `\printlist{publisher}` and `\printlist{location}`. Check the documentation for the type of each field.

Comment: Magic, thank you! (Feel free to write it as an answer, and I'll accept)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`biblatex` 'fields' come in three major flavours

1. field printed with `\printfield`
2. list printed with `\printlist`
3. name list printed with `\printnames`

So you need to know the type of the 'field' you want to print and choose the correct `\print...` command.

You can find out about the type of each 'field' in the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), §2.2 *Entry Fields*.

Both `publisher` and `location` are actually lists, so you need

```
\printlist{publisher}
```

and

```
\printlist{location}
```

Comment: Thanks very much! -- I've just added a follow up question, which is extremely similar. If you have time to look at it, I'd be most appreciative :)

Comment: @SamT Please consider making that a new question. It is for an entirely different reason: `biblatex` simply does not know the field `mrclass` and `mrnumber`. You'll have to tell Biber about it, see the second part of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/150393/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/151628/35864 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/155532/35864. I'm currently writing up a lengthy answer to your other question, so you'll have to wait a bit for further input on that matter.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'll read your other (extensive!) answers first, as linked; hopefully I can work out how to do it from those! :)

Comment: So I was able to work out the majority of it :) -- there was just a small part that I wasn't able to get. If you are able to have a look at it, I'd be hugely grateful. Even if you can't, you've done loads for me today and I'm extremely grateful! (Link: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430862/appending-data-to-bibliography-with-biblatex)