# Appending Data to Bibliography with Biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I am trying to add a custom 'field' to my bibtex data, and then call that. However, I am getting a very strange scenario: when I call the field `mr`, then it works; when I call it `mrnumber`, then it doesn't work. Below is a MWE.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{ext-eprint.dbx}
\ProvidesFile{ext-eprint.dbx}[2016/09/11 extended stand-alone eprint fields]
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=verbatim]{arxiv,mr}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{arxiv,mr}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{AGHH:dynamic-cm,
    archivePrefix = {arXiv},
    eprinttype = {arxiv},
    eprint = {1606.07639},
    title = {Mixing Times of Random Walks on Dynamic Configuration Models},
    date = {2016-06-24},
    author = {Avena, Luca and G{\"u}lda{\c s}, Hakan and van der Hofstad, Remco and den Hollander, Frank},
    options = {useprefix=true}
}
@article{FR:giant-mixing,
    title = {The Evolution of the Mixing Rate of a Simple Random Walk on the Giant Component of a Random Graph},
    volume = {33},
    number = {1},
    journaltitle = {Random Structures \& Algorithms},
    urldate = {2018-03-22},
    date = {2008-05-12},
    pages = {68-86},
    author = {Fountoulakis, Nikolaos and Reed, Bruce A.},
    mr = {12}
}
@book{LPW:markov-mixing,
    location = {{Providence, RI, USA}},
    title = {Markov {{Chains}} and {{Mixing Times}}},
    isbn = {978-1-4704-2962-1},
    pagetotal = {xvi+447},
    publisher = {{American Mathematical Society}},
    date = {2017},
    author = {Levin, David A. and Peres, Yuval and Wilmer, Elizabeth L.},
    mr = {3726904},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[doi=false,isbn=false,url=false,
    backend=biber,
    style=numeric,
    datamodel=ext-eprint]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\makeatletter
\DeclareFieldFormat{arxiv}{%
    ---HOW DO I CUSTOMISE THIS??---}%\href{https://arxiv.org/abs/#1}}
\makeatother
\DeclareFieldFormat{mr}{%
    {\href{http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR#1}{MR#1}}}

\renewbibmacro*{eprint}{%
  \printfield{arxiv}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{mr}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iffieldundef{eprinttype}
    {\printfield{eprint}}
    {thisdoesappear\printfield[eprint:\strfield{eprinttype}]{eprint}}
}


\begin{document}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This prints out the following.
[image: Output]

However, if I replace all five references to `mr` with `mrnumber`, then I get the same output just without the `MR3726904` appended. I got the majority of the structure from `moewe`'s answer to [BibTeX fields for DOI, MR, Zbl and arxiv?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151628/bibtex-fields-for-doi-mr-zbl-and-arxiv).

As you may have noticed in the MWE, I do `\DeclareFieldFormat{arxiv}{...`, but whatever I put in here does not affect the output, only the `thisdoesappear` appears, and this is in an `\iffieldundef` statement. I do want to just use `eprint` for both `arXiv` and `MR`, because each item will have precisely one of these. I'd like to be able to customise the appearance of the arxiv part, as I have done with the MR part.

**Remark.** I know some of the other formatting isn't very nice, but don't worry about that: I've looked at that separately, and have just tried to put the minimal amount in for the example here.

Comment: `arxiv` is an eprinttype, so `DeclareFieldFormat` will not really work as you are trying to do it. I'm not sure I get what you want to achieve. As far as I understood, you want `mr` to function as an `eprinttype` the same way as `arxiv` does. Is that it?

Comment: I'd like to make "arXiv: 1606.07639" customisable, eg maybe write "available at arxiv.org/abs/1606.07369". I'd also like to be able to change the `mr` variable to `mrnumber` -- MathSciNet automatically outputs `mrnumber`, not `mr`, and so I don't want to have to go through all my references changing them from mrnumber to mr. Is that clearer? :)

Comment: One more thing to clear up. That answer you link to creates extra fields because the requirement was that a single paper belonged to more than one eprinttype. In your case, is it sufficient that each paper is either arXiv or MR (that is, not both)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things going on here. The most important thing is that `biblatex` distinguishes the explicitly defined `arxiv` and `mrnumber` field from the `eprint` field. The `eprint` field is special and its contents get special treatment.

1. In the MWE below `mrnumber` works for me. The code is just a result of replacing all `mr`s in your code with `mrnumber`.
2. If you want to change the output of arXiv-`eprint`s, you don't modify the field format `arxiv`, you need to modify `eprint:arxiv`. You can see that `eprint:arxiv` is used by examining the false branch of `iffieldundef{eprinttype}`: `\printfield[eprint:\strfield{eprinttype}]{eprint}`. This calls the field format `eprint:<eprinttype>`, so `eprint:arxiv` in our case.
   `\DeclareFieldFormat{arxiv}` works only if you use the `arxiv` field directly.
3. You could also use `eprint` for both arXiv and `mrnumber`, but then you would have to transform `mrnumber` to `eprint`s. This could be done automatically with a sourcemap. The advantage of that approach is that you don't need a new `.dbx` file. The disadvantage is that the `mrnumber` occupies the `eprint` slot.

The code below shows three ways to deal with MR numbers and arXiv links

1. Write the identifier into the `eprint` field and the type (`arxiv`, `mrnumber`) into `eprinttype` manually. See entries `AGHH:dynamic-cm` and `FR:giant-mixing`.
2. Use a dedicated `arxiv` and `mrnumber` field in the source. This is what `baez/online` and `LPW:markov-mixing` do. The implementation on the `biblatex` side can be done in two ways here.

   1. Internally re-map `arxiv = {foo}` to `eprint = {foo}` with `eprinttype = {arxiv}` and `mrnumber = {bar}` to `eprint = {bar}` with `eprinttype = {mrnumber}`. This is done with the out-`\iffalse`d source map below, the data model is not needed in that case. This results in the fields being treated just like `eprint`, which means `DeclareFieldFormat{eprint:arxiv}` and `DeclareFieldFormat{eprint:mrnumber}` are the formats responsible, the fields are printed with `\printfield[eprint:\strfield{eprinttype}]{eprint}`. The advantage of this approach is that you don't need a data model, the disadvantage is that the one `eprint` slot you have is occupied. On the `biblatex` side (i.e. for writing a `biblatex` style) this is equivalent to the first method.
   2. Declare the `arxiv` and `mrnumber` fields as native fields in a special data model and load the data model. The fields can be used independently and are controlled with `DeclareFieldFormat{arxiv}` and `DeclareFieldFormat{mrnumber}` and printed with `\printfield{arxiv}` and `\printfield{mrnumber}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{ext-eprint.dbx}
\ProvidesFile{ext-eprint.dbx}[2018/05/09 extended stand-alone eprint fields]
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=verbatim]{arxiv,mrnumber}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{arxiv,mrnumber}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@online{AGHH:dynamic-cm,
  eprinttype    = {arxiv},
  eprint        = {1606.07639},
  title         = {Mixing Times of Random Walks on Dynamic Configuration Models},
  date          = {2016-06-24},
  author        = {Avena, Luca and G{\"u}lda{\c s}, Hakan and van der Hofstad, Remco and den Hollander, Frank},
  options       = {useprefix=true}
}
@online{baez/online,
  author  = {Baez, John C. and Lauda, Aaron D.},
  title   = {Higher-Dimensional Algebra {V}: 2-Groups},
  date    = {2004-10-27},
  version = 3,
  arxiv   = {math/0307200v3},
}
@article{FR:giant-mixing,
  title        = {The Evolution of the Mixing Rate of a Simple Random Walk on the Giant Component of a Random Graph},
  volume       = {33},
  number       = {1},
  journaltitle = {Random Structures \& Algorithms},
  urldate      = {2018-03-22},
  date         = {2008-05-12},
  pages        = {68-86},
  author       = {Fountoulakis, Nikolaos and Reed, Bruce A.},
  eprinttype   = {mrnumber},
  eprint       = {12},
}
@book{LPW:markov-mixing,
  location  = {Providence, RI, USA},
  title     = {Markov Chains and Mixing Times},
  isbn      = {978-1-4704-2962-1},
  pagetotal = {xvi+447},
  publisher = {American Mathematical Societ},
  date      = {2017},
  author    = {Levin, David A. and Peres, Yuval and Wilmer, Elizabeth L.},
  mrnumber  = {3726904},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[doi=false,isbn=false,url=false,
  backend=biber,
  style=numeric,
  datamodel=ext-eprint, % comment this out to see what the data model does
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{arxiv}{%
  arXiv\addcolon\space
    \ifhyperref
      {\href{https://arxiv.org/abs/#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
      {\nolinkurl{#1}}%
  \addspace
  as field}
\DeclareFieldFormat{eprint:arxiv}{%
  arXiv\addcolon\space
    \ifhyperref
      {\href{https://arxiv.org/abs/#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
      {\nolinkurl{#1}}%
  \addspace
  via eprint}

\DeclareFieldFormat{mrnumber}{%
  \ifhyperref
    {\href{http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR#1}{MR#1}}
    {MR#1}%
  \addspace
  real field}
\DeclareFieldFormat{eprint:mrnumber}{%
  \ifhyperref
    {\href{http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR#1}{MR#1}}
    {MR#1}%
  \addspace
  eprint}

% This map maps all mrnumber fields to eprints with eprinttype mrnumber
% and all arxiv fields to eprint with eprinttype arxiv
% If you remove the \iffalse and \fi, this becomes active,
% in that case the datamodel is not needed any more.
\iffalse
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=mrnumber, fieldtarget=eprint, final]
      \step[fieldset=eprinttype, fieldvalue=mrnumber]
    }
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=arxiv, fieldtarget=eprint, final]
      \step[fieldset=eprinttype, fieldvalue=arxiv]
    }
  }
}
\fi

\renewbibmacro*{eprint}{%
  \printfield{arxiv}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{mrnumber}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iffieldundef{eprinttype}
    {\printfield{eprint}}
    {\printfield[eprint:\strfield{eprinttype}]{eprint}}}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Did you have to manually edit the bibdata to put in `eprinttype = {mrnumber}` and `eprint = {12}`? I'm trying to avoid that. I see though that if I comment out the `datamodel` part, and remove the `\iffalse ... \fi`, then it works *exactly* as desired with the `mrnumber` field. You're a TeX genius!

Comment: @SamT Yes and no. The answer shows essentially three possible ways to deal with these identifiers. I have updated the answer to clarify this. If you want to keep `arxiv` and `mrnumber` fields from wherever you get your data from, only the way 2.1 or 2.2 are interesting for you. Way 1 indeed requires manual adjustments.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've implemented Method 2.1 -- at least, I'm pretty sure that's what I've done! [See https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYe1P.png for a snapshot]

Comment: @SamT In that case the `\printfield{arxiv}` and `\printfield{mrnumber}` lines do nothing. In fact you can simply delete the entire `\renewbibmacro*{eprint}` block, the default definition `\newbibmacro*{eprint}{%
  \iffieldundef{eprinttype}
    {\printfield{eprint}}
    {\printfield[eprint:\strfield{eprinttype}]{eprint}}}` should be good enough for you. If we ignore the `thisdoesappear` and a possibly unwanted space created by forgetting to add a `%` in the last line of the definition. I have also edited the field formats to work even if `hyperref` is not loaded.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm so grateful :) -- I've literally spent 7hrs+ on this, and I'd still have so far to go if it weren't for you :)

Comment: I was actually able to delete the `\begin{filecontents}{ext-eprint.dbx}...` and have it still work...

Comment: @SamT Yes, if you don't load the `datamodel` then that file is not needed. That bloc just creates the file `ext-eprint.dbx` with the specified content. Since you use the source mapping solution you don't need the data model at all.

Comment: @SamT Indeed gusbrs' answers shows the minimal code required for your chosen solution (extracted from my solution: https://gist.github.com/moewew/63872b2e661b893ff3ad0bdbc5c40138). The code in the answer here was set up to show all three methods at once. If you settle on one, you can kick out the code for the other methods.

Comment: @moewe Would you like to include the isolated chosen case in your answer? (I'll delete mine if you do). I only answered this one because I was almost done when you posted and felt the simple case might be useful. But I'm afraid the OP is getting mixed signals here.

Comment: I must confess, having the multiple versions in the one MWE is a bit confusing for me, as I'm not sure exactly which bits work for which. That said, combined with gusbrs' answer I'm pretty sure I'm now at least fairly well understanding! :) -- thank you both!

Answer (score 2):

This is a suggestion for you to use the easily extensible eprint facilities of `biblatex` (moewe's [third suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/430878/105447)).

For that, you have to create a field format for your desired new eprint in the format biblatex expects. In your case `eprint:mr`:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{eprint:mr}{% based on eprint:jstor
  \autocap{a}vailable\space at\space MR\addcolon\space
  \ifhyperref
    {\href{http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}}}
```

You can keep `mrnumber` and remap it to `eprint` with:

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=mrnumber, fieldtarget=eprint, final]
      \step[fieldset=eprinttype, fieldvalue=mr]
    }
  }
}
```

This also sets `eprinttype` to `mr` for all entries which contain a `mrnumber`.

As to customizing `arXiv`, you should use `\DeclareFieldFormat{eprint:arxiv}`, as explained by moewe.

Putting things together:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{AGHH:dynamic-cm,
    eprinttype = {arxiv},
    eprint = {1606.07639},
    title = {Mixing Times of Random Walks on Dynamic Configuration Models},
    date = {2016-06-24},
    author = {Avena, Luca and G{\"u}lda{\c s}, Hakan and van der Hofstad, Remco and den Hollander, Frank},
    options = {useprefix=true}
}
@article{FR:giant-mixing,
    title = {The Evolution of the Mixing Rate of a Simple Random Walk on the Giant Component of a Random Graph},
    volume = {33},
    number = {1},
    journaltitle = {Random Structures \& Algorithms},
    urldate = {2018-03-22},
    date = {2008-05-12},
    pages = {68-86},
    author = {Fountoulakis, Nikolaos and Reed, Bruce A.},
    mrnumber = {12}
}
@book{LPW:markov-mixing,
    location = {{Providence, RI, USA}},
    title = {Markov {{Chains}} and {{Mixing Times}}},
    isbn = {978-1-4704-2962-1},
    pagetotal = {xvi+447},
    publisher = {{American Mathematical Society}},
    date = {2017},
    author = {Levin, David A. and Peres, Yuval and Wilmer, Elizabeth L.},
    mrnumber = {3726904},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[doi=false,isbn=false,url=false,
    backend=biber,
    style=numeric]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=mrnumber, fieldtarget=eprint, final]
      \step[fieldset=eprinttype, fieldvalue=mr]
    }
  }
}

\makeatletter
\DeclareFieldFormat{eprint:arxiv}{%
  \autocap{a}vailable\space at\space arXiv\addcolon\space% <- changed here, relative to the default definition
  \ifhyperref
    {\href{https://arxiv.org/\abx@arxivpath/#1}{%
       \nolinkurl{#1}%
       \iffieldundef{eprintclass}
         {}
         {\addspace\texttt{\mkbibbrackets{\thefield{eprintclass}}}}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}%
     \iffieldundef{eprintclass}
       {}
       {\addspace\texttt{\mkbibbrackets{\thefield{eprintclass}}}}}}
\makeatother

\DeclareFieldFormat{eprint:mr}{% based on eprint:jstor
  \autocap{a}vailable\space at\space MR\addcolon\space
  \ifhyperref
    {\href{http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}}}


\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Did you have to manually type in `eprinttype = {mr}` into all your bibliography entries? I'm trying to avoid having do manually edit them

Comment: @SamT I've adapted the answer for the `eprinttype` to be automatically set to `mr` for all entries which contain a `mrnumber`.

Comment: I see, thank you. I suppose this has the advantage over moewe's that it doesn't require `\begin{filecontents*}{ext-eprint.dbx} ...` -- in fact, it's almost exactly the same, just without this, but with `\makeatletter ... \makeatother`

Comment: @SamT moewe's answer includes different alternatives. As I mentioned, this just expands the third suggestion, for which he says himself "The advantage of that approach is that you don't need a new `.dbx` file." The `.dbx` is included in his code because it is needed for the other suggestions. Here `\makeatletter ... \makeatother` is only used to redefine the formating directive for `eprint:arxiv` because I took the original definition, which contains the macro `\abx@arxivpath`. But I suppose moewe's definition of it would also work here.