# Biblatex use groupauthor when author is missing

Tags: biblatex, citing, biber, author

In a custom citation with Biblatex, is there a way to use `groupauthor` when the field `author` is empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if there are any authors with `\ifnameundef{author}`, so the following might work

```
\ifnameundef{author}
  {% no author, so try groupauthor
   \printnames{groupauthor}}
  {% we have an author, so print that
   \printnames{author}}
```

---

Note that there are three different types of fields for `biblatex`.

- (literal/normal) fields
- literal lists
- name lists

These three types are implemented differently and are usually handled with different macros.

- Fields are printed with `\printfield` and tested with `\iffieldundef`.
- Literal lists are printed with `\printlist` and tested with `\iflistundef`.
- Name lists are printed with `\printnames` and tested with `\ifnameundef`.

You can find out the types in the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), §2.2 *Entry Fields*.

See also [Unable to Call "Publisher" or "Location" in Biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/430833/35864), [How to extract BibTeX entries (as DOI, abstract, etc.)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/207591/35864).

---

I only know of one `biblatex` style that uses `groupauthor`: `biblatex-apa`. `groupauthor` will be removed in the next release of `biblatex-apa`, because it was not semantically meaningful (https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/pull/144): There is a reading of the APA style guidelines that doesn't require special treatment of group authors/corporate authors. All apparent differences in output can be explained by the absence of a given name part.

Comment: When I use this, the field is always considered undefined. I tried ``\ifnameundef{title}{\thefield{title}}{nothing}`` and the title appeared. Why?

Comment: @Dunno What one ordinarily calls 'field' in `biblatex` comes in three types: Literal field, list and name list. You need to use the correct command for the type of field you are handling. `author` is a name list, so you use `\ifnameundef`. `title` is a literal field, so you test it with `\iffieldundef`. (See the edit.) If you use the wrong test for the field you will always get the 'undefined' branch.

Comment: Thank you. I was going to edit my question with "``\ifnameundef{author}{author undefined}{name defined} \ifnameundef{title}{title undefined}{title defined}`` always detects my title as undefined". When I saw your last comment, I was going to ask here I can see which field belongs to which type. You answered both.

Comment: How could I print the date ? ``\iffieldundef{date}{}{\printfield{date}}`` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Dunno The date is special. You print it with `\printdate`. You can check if it exists with `\iffieldundef{year}`. Note that `biblatex`'s `\print...` commands are usually pretty good at doing nothing when the field is undefined, so often `\iffieldundef` tests are not required.  E.g. `\ifnameundef{title}{}{\printfield{title}}` could just be `\printfield{title}`. Similarly `\iffieldundef{year}{}{\printdate}` is no better than `\printdate`. The whole point of `\setunit` and friends is to handle missing field values.

Comment: I needed this check to print a word before the date. Thank you for your answer.